# How to call the previous page function in MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, maui

**My problem:**
My parent page (AdminPanel.xaml) contains a function: updateAllMaterialList()

It's the page previous one on the navigation stack.

Now on the AddUser.xaml page, I try to navigate back by calling updateAllMaterialList() like this:

```
    private async void GoToBack(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    await Navigation.PopAsync();

    NavigationPage navPage = (NavigationPage)App.Current.MainPage;
    Page page = navPage.Navigation.NavigationStack[navPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1];
    ((AdminPanel)page).updateAllMaterialList();

    }
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: it seems to be a common method that could be called by different pages, why don't you define it in a separate class? a viewmodel if we talk about mvvm pattern.

Comment: You can place the method call in OnAppearing, which should fire on forward and back navigation.  Or you could pass a navigation parameter on back navigation that tells the page to refresh its data

Comment: Or try [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as they said, you can use the OnAppearing and everything works great. But I also found this way:

```
    var navPage = App.Current.MainPage;
        if (navPage.Navigation != null)
        {
            navPage = navPage.Navigation.NavigationStack[navPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2];
            (navPage as AdminPanel).UpdateAllMaterialList();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First I want to point out, that there is good reason not keep your business logic in your pages.

I recommend that you check CommunityToolkit.MVVM/MAUI.
And then add some service, to do this work for you.
Or use EvenToCommandBehavior to bind your page events.(Appearing, Loading, etc..)
Or use Messenger to send/receive data between decoupled segments.

The way you are attempting to handle your logic and navigation will bring a lot of problems. One page navigation should have nothing to do with another page business logic.

Answer (score 0):

As Jason said, you can Generate `OnAppearing` method override in `AdminPanel.xaml.cs`, and add updateAllMaterialList() function to `OnAppearing`. So, whenever the AddUser.xaml page navigates to the AdminPanel.xaml page, it will call updateAllMaterialList() automatically. `OnAppearing` means that when the specified page appears, it will be called.

Comment: For more info you can refer to this doc: [Page.OnAppearing Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.onappearing?view=xamarin-forms).